# Transfer files from remote server to local machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, file-transfer

How can i directly transfer files from remote host to local machine if i have only access to remote server? I have tried scp and tail over ssh from local machine but I have to transfer data from remote machine using remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp to transfer files from server to server, server to local machine and local machine to server. Use the following commands

```
scp [OPTION] [user@]SRC_HOST:]file1 [user@]DEST_HOST:]file2
```

For options check the manual [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

Below is an example of downloading file from server to local machine

```
scp user1@foo.com:/var/www/html/foo.txt ~/Desktop/
```

Comment: With scp command i can download or transfer file from server to local or transfer from local to server. but if i have access for server machine and not local then how can i transfer files to local machine accessing the server machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [daggy](https://docs.daggy.dev/#getting-started).

Create sources config with files that you want to transfers and remote servers, from which you want to transfer (files.yaml):

```yaml
    aliases:  
        - &my_commands
            file1:
                exec: cat file1
                extension: log
            file2:
                exec: cat file2
                extension: log
            
        - &ssh_auth
            user: {{env_USER}}
            passphrase: {{env_PASSWORD}}
                
    sources:
        localhost:
            type: local
            commands: *my_commands
        remotehost:
            host: 192.168.1.9
            type: ssh2
            parameters: *ssh_auth
            commands: *my_commands
        remotehost2:
            host: 192.168.1.10
            type: ssh2
            parameters: *ssh_auth
            commands: *my_commands
```

Run daggy:

```sh
    daggy files.yaml
```